# Remote file upload error

Tags: php, upload

Can somebody help with this script?

I'm looking for upload via url to my server.

I saw many of options but no one does not work for me.

This is what I'm trying to do

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<script type="text/javascript">
//Alerts to errors.
window.onerror=function(msg, url, linenumber){var logerror='Error message: ' + msg + '. Url: ' + url + 'Line Number: ' + linenumber;alert(logerror);return false}
</script>
<title>Upload Form</title>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
margin: 0 auto;
width:900px;
font-family:serif
}
#upload_box
{
background-color: LightBlue;
border:1px solid Black;
padding:20px;
margin-top:40px;
width: 50%;
}
</style>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['myupload']))
{
    define('BUFSIZ', 4095);
    $url = $_POST['upload'];
    echo 'Trying with fread() ';
    $target = 'up/';
    $nname = basename($url);
    $info = pathinfo($url);
    var_dump($info);
    $parse = parse_url($url);
    echo '<br/><br/>';
    if(isset($_POST['nname'])){
        $nname = $_POST['nname'];
    }
    if(fopen($url, 'rb')){
        $rfile = fopen($url, 'rb');
        $lfile = fopen($target.$nname, 'wb');
        while(!feof($rfile)){
            fwrite($lfile, fread($rfile, BUFSIZ), BUFSIZ);
            fclose($rfile);
            fclose($lfile);
        }
    }else{
        echo "Can't read from this directory";
    }
    $fp = fsockopen($parse['host'], 80, $errno, $errstr, 300);
    if (!$fp) {
        echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
    } else {
        $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $out .= "Host: ".$url."\r\n";
        $out .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 Firefox/3.6.12\r\n";
        $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
        fwrite($fp, $out);
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            echo fgets($fp, BUFSIZ);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
}

?> 

</head>
<body>
<div id="upload_box">
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="upload"><label>URL</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="nname"><label>NEW Name</label><br/>
<input type="submit" name="myupload" value="Upload File">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the result is:

```
Warning: fopen(http://xxx.co.uk/xxxx/xxxx.mp3):  failed to open stream: Permission denied in
```

and for fsockopen is the same problem

```
Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to xxx.co.uk:80 (Permission denied) in xxx/index.php on line 53
Permission denied (13)
```

Comment: i think the warnings provide enough information.

Comment: i know that but how to fix it??

i try many hosts and not works??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it

it was a outgoing connection on my host

allowed all and fixed ;)